# Why does my css change work in inspector but not in customiser?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, inspector

I'm trying to change the social media icons' colour globally wherever they were added with the theme's "social media icons" shortcode via Visual Composer. I've located the class "site-social-icons-shortcode" using Chrome's Inspector and added the css below using Wordpress's Customiser. It works in Inspector, and on the page specific CSS Customiser, but not in the global CSS Customiser. What am I doing wrong?

http://evermanapparel.co.za/social-media-icon-colour-test/

```
.site-social-icons-shortcode {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Try - .wpb_wrapper .site-social-icons-shortcode ul li a { color: #f1b828; }

Comment: @Gerard Tried that, no luck.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin, that makes a lot of sense. I tried it in "code snippet", but was not able to replicate the problem. So much learning to do.

Comment: Try to get as specific as possible with your selectors, but avoid over-qualifying, also make sure this isn't a caching issue where you are being served a cached stylesheet that is not reflecting the latest additions to it.

Comment: `.site-social-icons-shortcode .fa {
    color: red;
}` That should be all you need really.

Comment: No luck @UncaughtTypeError. Have a look at Shahil's string below. His 2nd/alternative suggestion turned all the icons red except for whichever one is list first in the css.

Comment: @JohnBlignaut That style rule (for the first type in the list) is valid, you can find it through viewing the source, and when you do, you see all those styles minified on one line, the first rule immediately follows a lengthy comment, I suspect that any rule following this comment will not apply, probably due to the nature of minification in this case. See what happens when you remove this comment. You may find that this style rule now applies, if you can resolve this issue I'm sure you'll find the global style I suggested above will apply as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this css to generally target all the icons

```
.site-social-icons-shortcode i {
    color: red;
}
```

Alternatively if you need to color each icons differently try this

```
.site-social-icons-shortcode .site-social-icons-facebook i {
    color: blue;
}
.site-social-icons-shortcode .site-social-icons-twitter i {
    color: red;
}
```

You can override the css if theer are multiple csss targeting (Not a good solution)

```
.site-social-icons-shortcode .site-social-icons-twitter i { color:blue !important; }
```

Comment: Getting so close! This seems very odd though. I used your suggestion to color each icon separately and it worked for all of them except Facebook. What gives?

Comment: Nope. The Facebook icon is still the only one giving a mysterious problem.

Comment: Interesting observation: it seems to be an issue with whichever class selector I put first. When I moved the Facebook css selector down it turned red but then Twitter defaulted to grey again.

Comment: .site-social-icons-shortcode .site-social-icons-twitter i { color:blue !important; } This should work

Answer (score 1):

you can put this css: color: #F1B831; on "http://evermanapparel.co.za/wp-content/themes/shopkeeper/css/styles.css" line no.17813 in this class .site-social-icons-shortcode

Comment: Thanks, but would prefer using Wordpress's Customise and not to alter the core files.